# Need a second help in a second example of bounded linear operators with estimates of the norm.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, proof-explanation

A part of the example is given in the following picture:

[image]

But it is not clear for me:

1-how the first (line)inequality lead to the second (line)inequality?

2- Also in the second line in the second term it is not clear for  me why the the square is put over **the integral** $\int_{a}^{b} |k(t,s)f(s)|ds$ and not only on $|k(t,s)f(s)|$?

3- Also the last term in the second line is not clear for me how it comes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\|Kf\|=\left(\int_{a}^{b}|(Kf)(t)|^{2}dt\right)^{1/2},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\|Kf\|^{2}=\int_{a}^{b}|(Kf)(t)|^{2}dt,
\end{align*}
but 
\begin{align*}
(Kf)(t)=\int_{a}^{b}k(t,s)f(s)ds,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
|(Kf)(t)|\leq\int_{a}^{b}|k(t,s)f(s)|ds\leq\left(\int_{a}^{b}|k(t,s)|^{2}ds\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{a}^{b}|f(s)|^{2}ds\right)^{1/2},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
|(Kf)(t)|^{2}\leq\left(\int_{a}^{b}|k(t,s)|^{2}ds\right)\left(\int_{a}^{b}|f(s)|^{2}ds\right),
\end{align*}
plugging in,
\begin{align*}
\|Kf\|^{2}\leq\int_{a}^{b}\left(\int_{a}^{b}|k(t,s)|^{2}ds\right)\left(\int_{a}^{b}|f(s)|^{2}ds\right)dt,
\end{align*}
but 
\begin{align*}
\left(\int_{a}^{b}|f(s)|^{2}ds\right)dt=\|f\|^{2},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\|Kf\|^{2}\leq\int_{a}^{b}\left(\int_{a}^{b}|k(t,s)|^{2}ds\right)\|f\|^{2}dt=\|f\|^{2}\int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{b}|k(t,s)|^{2}dsdt.
\end{align*}